# Trouble Installing iGraph on Windows (i386 and x64)

Tags: python, windows, r, compiler-construction

I usually install R packages using the command below, but it will not work for the network graph ad-on iGraph. T think this is because I am using the new version of R (2.12) which seems to have changed package installation (now split between i386/x64).

My question is, what is the easiest way to get up and running with iGraph. Should I get up to speed troubleshooting compiling in windows, or should i downgrade to an earlier version of R?

```
> install.packages('igraph', type='source')
trying URL 'http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/igraph_0.5.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1135577 bytes (1.1 Mb)
opened URL
downloaded 1.1 Mb

* installing *source* package 'igraph' ...
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'igraph'
* removing 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-212~1.0/library/igraph'

The downloaded packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\SSSS\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpN4LiQG\downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("igraph", type = "source") :
  installation of package 'igraph' had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 2.12.0 using the following GUI commands worked for me
Packages -> Select Repositories -> CTRL Click all repositories
Packages -> Install Packages -> Click igraph

Once you have this done, be sure to add "library(igraph)" to your script.

Comment: Brilliant - this worked...Although igraph is not on CRAN it is 64-bit binaries are available at bioconductor.org

Answer (score 0):

Generally users of Windows packages are discouraged from be installing from source, but I see that the Windows version has not passed CRAN Package checks. Have you gotten  [Murdoch's RTools bundle](http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/installer.html) downloaded and properly configured?

Here's a link that may be useful if your target is Win64:
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Rtools-for-building-64-bit-windows-packages-td2021034.html